# Dismiss firefox update popup with WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, chimp.js

I want to dismiss this popup when I'm running my tests with webdriverIO but I'm not able to do it.
I'm using chimp to run my tests

I tried with `browser.alertdismiss()` but it didn't work. Also, I tried using this [NPM package](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/packages/wdio-firefox-profile-service) and adding this configuration but seems that firefox it's not taking that profile

My configuration file

```
// wdio.conf.js
const config = {
  // ...
  services: ['firefox-profile'],
  firefoxProfile: {
    "app.update.enabled": true,
      "app.update.auto": true,
      "app.update.silent": true,
      "privacy.popups.firstTime": true,
      "update.showSlidingNotification": false,
      "update_notifications.enabled": false ,
  },
  // ...
};

module.export = config;
```